# adding collaborators to github submodules only

Tags: github, git-submodules

Is there a way to give a user only access to a submodule in a repo on github? I know I can do that for the entirely repo but I only want to do so for a submodule.

Answer (score 0):

A git submodule is another git repo altogether. If you look at the .gitmodules file, it will show you the URL for each of them. Each has its own access control, so you can grant or deny access to it individually as much as you can any other git repo. You won't see anything in the github UI for the module that has the submodules, to it the .gitmodules file is just a file. Presumably, if you are maintaining a project with submodules, you know how to edit that file -- and for the purpose at hand, you have to just read it to see where on github each of the submodules lives.

Comment: How can I do that? I don't see any options to do so on the github UI.